# Arch Linux Terminal is Garbled After Install (latest)

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux

I've installed Arch Linux successfully on a Virtual Machine (VMWare) with no issues. However, when I installed Arch on an older physical box I'm getting a bit of weirdness (Old Gateway PIII, 766 Mhz 256MB RAM)

When booting up, Grub comes up and shows its loading text and the option for picking boot options fine, I can look at it fine, no errors in the way the text is displayed, looks like the Terminus-16 font.

However when it goes to a prompt, the Text is extremely corrupted and garbled, the characters are very "fat" to the point of being unreadable. The system DOES seem to work, as I can type in commands blindly and it seems to be OK, (reboot, power off, even cat /etc/ls).

I can type 'reset' all I want and the screen resets but with the same garbled text.

I've checked everything I could find, even resorted to trying creating the vconsole.conf file... nothing seems to work...

As far as I can tell, the system boots great, runs commands... just can't see what I'm typing...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other fonts:

```
setfont sun12x22.psfu
```

The availables fonts are in the `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/` folder.